# How to transform these statements in Predicate form while using logical operators

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

Write the following statements in predicate form, using logical operators $\land, \lor$, (NOT - negation but don't know where the symbol is :/) ($\color{blue}{\text{edit: it is }\neg}$ `\neg`), and quantifiers $\forall,\exists $. Below $\Bbb Z^+$ denotes all positive integers $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

I need help with this first statement:
For any $(x, y) \in {\Bbb Z^+}^2$ the equation $x^2 + y^2 - z = 0$ has a solution $z \in\Bbb Z^+ $

Answer (score 1):

$$
(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{Z^+})(\exists z\in\mathbb{Z^+})(x^2+y^2-z=0)
$$

Comment: would you care to elaborate how ?:) How I did was $ ∀x,y ( x^2 + y^2 = z) $

Comment: I see "all of x , and all of y are part of positive intergers. There is one z part of the positive interger set satisfied by the equation". I have a feeling this might be wrong

Comment: @Marc-AndreLeclair What you did doesn't make any sense--what exactly is $z$ in your formulation?

Comment: @Marc-AndreLeclair For any $x,y\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ [i.e., $(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{Z^+})]$, there is a solution $z\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ [i.e., $(\exists z\in\mathbb{Z^+})$] to the equation $x^2+y^2-z=0$. Putting that together gives the answer. Can't say anything beyond that.

Comment: I just realized what you meant... I saw the equation $ x^2 + y^2 - z = 0 $ as $ x^2 + y^2 = z $ therefore meaning the z solution is equal to x^2 and y^2.. so you basically have to break it down. By the way, if you say that your $ UoD= Z+ $ , would that allow me to ommit saying that it is always element of z+ ?

Comment: What is $UoD= Z+$ supposed to mean?

Comment: Sorry I'm using my chromebook and it doesn't want to indicate $ Z+ $ --> means just the positive integers. As for UoD my teacher used it to define the "Universal of Discourse"

Comment: @Marc-AndreLeclair I really don't get what the issue is here. If you're told explicitly that you're dealing only with elements from $\mathbb{Z^+}$, then you could simply write $(\forall x,y)(\exists z)(x^2+y^2-z=0)$, but it's good practice to indicate what set your elements belong to.

Comment: Oh, it was just notation question, nothing of an issue. Sorry if I made it more complicated. It was just wondering if the notation was right if I just put explicitly what I'm dealing it. But I'll practice the way you guys put it if it is the one that is generally accepted!

Comment: Yes, do what is generally accepted :)